# ASP.NET equivalent to JSF Session Bean

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, session-state

I'm fairly new to both JSF and ASP.NET, and as far as I can understand (correct me if I'm wrong), while using session scoped beans in JSF, data is stored on the server side temporarily, for the components. But in ASP.NET it seems that such temporary data is stored in a hidden field in the page itself, called Viewstate.

Am I right in assuming this? Is there anything in ASP.NET that'll automatically manage the data and store it server side in objects (like JSF does) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET has support for both a Viewstate and a Session state.  Here is a link to some info regarding session state.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

I'd recommend that you try to avoid using the viewstate at all, and use the session state sparingly.  You should strive to keep your ASP.NET applications as "stateless" as possible.  Do not over-use the session state or you could experience scalability issues down the road.  Consider the following alternatives.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145945/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041600-2.shtml

Comment: Wow, thanks for the prompt reply! This seems to be my answer, but then I can see that ASP.NET lacks the better encapsulated style of JSF beans.

Comment: You don't need to store the viewstate for a control in the page itself.  You can add a custom viewstate provider that uses a database or other such server-side storage mechanism.  That perhaps would be closer to the JSF bean style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

```
Session["FirstName"] = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
Session["LastName"] = LastNameTextBox.Text;
```

Where the data is actually stored (in memory, in a database) can be configured. Depending on your situation, it may be better to store state in the view. Using the view state would be better in any situation where a single user might have two browser windows open at the same time, and expect them to keep separate state, such as the current stage in a wizard workflow.

Comment: Note that that link is a good page on the subject, and it was the first search result for "asp.net session". The rest of the links on the first page of results also look good.

Comment: Thanks, I actually thought (now am sure) that something like the above could be done, but it's not as encapsulated as the JSF implementation.